# A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)] - Android webview crash

Tags: android, webview, chromium

When I am finishing my fragment and going to some other activity, I am getting a crash with this error :

> A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(243)]

I am doing this on onDestroy():

```
      mWebView.clearHistory();
      mWebView.clearCache(true);
      mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
      WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();
```

Can someone tell me the reason/fix?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to call the mWebView.destroy() after WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData(). It destroys the internal state of this WebView. This method should be called after this WebView has been removed from the view system. No other methods may be called on this WebView after destroy.

//formatted the code

```
  mWebView.clearHistory();
  mWebView.clearCache(true);
  mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
  WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();
  mWebView.destroy();
```

Comment: Thank you @pk4393 for so exact solution. :)